# Using javascript and jquery, to populate related select boxes with array structure

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522/javascript-array-with-a-mix-of-literals-and-arrays), I have been able to populate a select box based on the selection of another select box. ( [I posted my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57522/javascript-array-with-a-mix-of-literals-and-arrays#58062)) Pulling the data from an array structure built server-side, stored in a .js file and referenced in the html page.

Now I would like to add a third select box. If I had 3 sets of data (model, make, options) something like this (pseudo code):

```
cars : [Honda[Accord[Lx, Dx]], [Civic[2dr, Hatchback]],
   [Toyota[Camry[Blk, Red]], [Prius[2dr,4dr]]
```

Ex: If Honda were selected, the next select box would have [Accord Civic] and if Accord were selected the next select box would have [Lx Dx]

How can I

1) create an array structure to hold the data? such that

2) I can use the value from one select box to reference the needed values for the next select box

Thanks

**EDIT**

I can create the following, but can't figure out the references in a way that would help populate a select box

```
var cars = [
 {"makes"  : "Honda",
  "models"  : [
    {'Accord' : ["2dr","4dr"]} ,
    {'CRV'  : ["2dr","Hatchback"]} ,
    {'Pilot': ["base","superDuper"] } ]
 },
 {"makes"   :"Toyota",
  "models"  : [
    {'Prius'   : ["green","reallyGreen"]} ,
    {'Camry'   : ["sporty","square"]} ,
    {'Corolla' : ["cheap","superFly"] } ]
 } ] ;              

 alert(cars[0].models[0].Accord[0]); ---> 2dr
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I prefer data structure like this:

```
var carMakers = [
    { name: 'Honda', models: [
            { name: 'Accord', features: ['2dr', '4dr'] },
            { name: 'CRV', features: ['2dr', 'Hatchback'] },
            { name: 'Pilot', features: ['base', 'superDuper'] }
        ]},

    { name: 'Toyota', models: [
            { name: 'Prius', features: ['green', 'superGreen'] },
            { name: 'Camry', features: ['sporty', 'square'] },
            { name: 'Corolla', features: ['cheap', 'superFly'] }
        ]}
];
```

Given the three select lists with id's: 'maker', 'model' and 'features' you can manipulate them with this (I believe this is pretty self explanatory):

```
// returns array of elements whose 'prop' property is 'value'
function filterByProperty(arr, prop, value) {
    return $.grep(arr, function (item) { return item[prop] == value });
}

// populates select list from array of items given as objects: { name: 'text', value: 'value' }
function populateSelect(el, items) {
    el.options.length = 0;
    if (items.length > 0)
        el.options[0] = new Option('please select', '');

    $.each(items, function () {
        el.options[el.options.length] = new Option(this.name, this.value);
    });
}

// initialization
$(document).ready(function () {
    // populating 1st select list
    populateSelect($('#maker').get(0), $.map(carMakers, function(maker) { return { name: maker.name, value: maker.name} }));

    // populating 2nd select list
    $('#maker').bind('change', function() {
        var makerName = this.value,
            carMaker = filterByProperty(carMakers, 'name', makerName),
            models = [];

        if (carMaker.length > 0)
            models = $.map(carMaker[0].models, function(model) { return { name: model.name, value: makerName + '.' + model.name} });

        populateSelect($('#model').get(0), models);
        $('#model').trigger('change');
    });

    // populating 3rd select list
    $('#model').bind('change', function () {
        var nameAndModel = this.value.split('.'),
            features = [];

        if (2 == nameAndModel.length) {
            var makerName = nameAndModel[0], 
                carModel = nameAndModel[1],
                carMaker = filterByProperty(carMakers, 'name', makerName);

            if (carMaker.length > 0) {
                var model = filterByProperty(carMaker[0].models, 'name', carModel)

                if (model.length > 0)
                    features = $.map(model[0].features, function(feature) { return { name: feature, value: makerName + '.' + carModel + '.' + feature} })
            }
        }

        populateSelect($('#feature').get(0), features);
    })

    // alerting value on 3rd select list change
    $('#feature').bind('change', function () { 
        if (this.value.length > 0)
            alert(this.value);
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks for the effort you put into your answer. I tried your code and it worked, but I don't have time right now to learn exactly how it works...will come back to it later..but I'm using the array structure...and I think I now understand how to create these arrays. Thanks again

Comment: The data structure is actually a Javascript object. You can find here a decent JSON tutorial: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_%28_JavaScript_Object_Notation_%29

Comment: Using $.grep and $.map for this is just the masters stroke. Fantastic solution, I just used it as a basis for something similar and feel like a better programmer for it.

Awesome solution.

Comment: Excellent code for create 3 related select boxes. Just what I needed today!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the answer from @Marko Dunic, I was able to build an array (data) structure that can be referenced to populate 3 select boxes. I didn't use the implementation code only because I didn't completely understand it...it works as posted. I will come back to this code later as I learn jQuery.
My code is posted below (obviously, your reference to jQuery may be different)

```
<html><head>
<script language="Javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var cars = [
{ name: 'Honda', models: [
{ name: 'Accord', features: ['2dr', '4dr'] },
{ name: 'CRV', features: ['2dr', 'Hatchback'] },
{ name: 'Pilot', features: ['base', 'superDuper'] }
   ]},
{ name: 'Toyota', models: [
{ name: 'Prius', features: ['green', 'superGreen'] },
{ name: 'Camry', features: ['sporty', 'square'] },
{ name: 'Corolla', features: ['cheap', 'superFly'] }
   ]
 }
];
$(function() {
var options = '' ;
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    var opt = cars[i].name ;
    if (i == 0){  options += '<option selected value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>'; }
    else {options += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>'; } 
}
$("#maker").html(options);   // populate select box with array

var options = '' ;
for (var i=0; i < cars[0].models.length; i++) { 
    var opt = cars[0].models[0].name ;
    if (i==0){options += '<option selected value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';}
    else {options += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';} 
}
$("#model").html(options);   // populate select box with array

var options = '' ;
for (var i=0; i < cars[0].models[0].features.length; i++) { 
    var opt = cars[0].models[0].features[i] ;
    if (i==0){options += '<option selected value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';}
    else {options += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';}
}
$("#feature").html(options);   // populate select box with array

$("#maker").bind("click",
    function() {
        $("#model").children().remove() ;       // clear select box
        for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
            if (cars[i].name == this.value) {
                var options = '' ;
                for (var j=0; j < cars[i].models.length; j++) { 
                    var opt= cars[i].models[j].name ;
                    if (j==0) {options += '<option selected value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';}
                    else {options += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';} 
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        $("#model").html(options);   // populate select box with array

        $("#feature").children().remove() ;     // clear select box
        for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
            for(var j=0; j<cars[i].models.length; j++) {
                if(cars[i].models[j].name == $("#model").val()) {
                    var options = '' ;
                    for (var k=0; k < cars[i].models[j].features.length; k++) { 
                        var opt = cars[i].models[j].features[k] ;
                        if (k==0){options += '<option selected value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';}
                        else {options += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';}
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $("#feature").html(options);   // populate select box with array
    });

    $("#model").bind("click",
        function() {
            $("#feature").children().remove() ;     // clear select box
            for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) {
                for(var j=0; j<cars[i].models.length; j++) {
                    if(cars[i].models[j].name == this.value) {
                        var options = '' ;
                        for (var k=0; k < cars[i].models[j].features.length; k++) { 
                            var opt = cars[i].models[j].features[k] ;
                            if (k==0){options += '<option selected value="' + opt  + '">' + opt  + '</option>';}
                            else {options += '<option value="' + opt  + '">' + opt  + '</option>';}
                        }
                        break ;
                    }
                }
            }
            $("#feature").html(options);   // populate select box with array
    });
});
</script>
</head> <body>
<div id="selection">
<select id="maker"size="10" style="{width=75px}"></select>
<select id="model" size="10" style="{width=75px}"></select>
<select id="feature" size="10"style="{width=75px}"></select>
</div></body></html>
```

Comment: +1 for filling in a gaping hole in my jQuery+JSON knowledge. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I really liked the solution by @Marko Dunic, but it didn't meet my needs for attaching IDs to the options.  Once I attached the IDs, I realized that I could make the JS code even smaller and simpler.  My solution is designed for when the data comes from a relational database, and the JSON input data retains the relational structure with Primary/Foreign Keys.  Here is the JSON data:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Populate a select dropdown list with jQuery - WebDev Ingredients</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var types = [ 
            { typeID: 1, name: 'Domestic'},
            { typeID: 2, name: 'Import'},
            { typeID: 3, name: 'Boat'}
        ]
        var makes = [ 
            { typeID: 1, makeID: 1, name: 'Chevy'}, 
            { typeID: 1, makeID: 2, name: 'Ford'}, 
            { typeID: 1, makeID: 3, name: 'Delorean'}, 
            { typeID: 2, makeID: 4, name: 'Honda'}, 
            { typeID: 2, makeID: 5, name: 'Toyota'}, 
            { typeID: 2, makeID: 6, name: 'Saab'} 
        ]       
        var model = [ 
            { makeID: 1,  modelID: 1, name: 'Camaro'}, 
            { makeID: 1,  modelID: 2, name: 'Chevelle'}, 
            { makeID: 1,  modelID: 3, name: 'Nova'}, 
            { makeID: 2,  modelID: 4, name: 'Focus'}, 
            { makeID: 2,  modelID: 5, name: 'Galaxie'}, 
            { makeID: 2,  modelID: 6, name: 'Mustang'}, 
            { makeID: 4,  modelID: 7, name: 'Accord'},
            { makeID: 4,  modelID: 8, name: 'Civic'}, 
            { makeID: 4,  modelID: 9, name: 'Odyssey'}, 
            { makeID: 5,  modelID: 10, name: 'Camry'}, 
            { makeID: 5,  modelID: 11, name: 'Corolla'}
        ]
        // 
        // Put this in a stand alone .js file
        //
        // returns array of elements whose 'prop' property is 'value' 
        function filterByProperty(arr, prop, value) { 
            return $.grep(arr, function (item) { return item[prop] == value }); 
        } 
        // populates select list from array of items given as objects: { name: 'text', value: 'value' } 
        function populateSelect(el, items) { 
            el.options.length = 0; 
            if (items.length > 0) 
                el.options[0] = new Option('please select', ''); 
            $.each(items, function () { 
                el.options[el.options.length] = new Option(this.name, this.value); 
            }); 
        }  
        // initialization 
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            // populating 1st select list 
            populateSelect($('#sType').get(0), $.map(types, function(type) { return { name: type.name, value: type.typeID} }));      
             // populating 2nd select list 
            $('#sType').bind('change', function() { 
                var theModels = filterByProperty(makes, 'typeID', this.value);
                populateSelect($('#sMake').get(0), $.map(theModels, function(make) { return { name: make.name, value: make.makeID} })); 
                $('#sMake').trigger('change'); 
            }); 
             // populating 3nd select list 
            $('#sMake').bind('change', function() { 
                var theSeries = filterByProperty(model, 'makeID', this.value);  
                populateSelect($('#sModel').get(0), $.map(theSeries, function(model) { return { name: model.name, value: model.modelID} })); 
            }); 
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Enter values, click submit, and look at the post parameters
    <form method="get" action="index.php">
            <div id="selection"> 
                <select id="sType" name="type_id" style="{width=75px}"></select> 
                <select id="sMake"  name="make_id" style="{width=75px}"></select> 
                <select id="sModel"  name="model_id" style="{width=75px}"></select> 
            </div>
            <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that my solution shifts the functionality so that Make-Model are the 2nd and 3rd text boxes, and Type ( domestic, import, boat, etc. ) are the 1st level.  I got the boilerplate JS down to 23 lines (less comments) while retaining good formatting.

The JSON data is very easy to render from SQL queries, which are cached in java Lists on init because the Type-Make-Model rarely change.  I don't use any dynamic AJAX because that complicates the architecture, and I have a relatively small list of available values, so I just send it at the page request.

"Solutions should be a simple as possible, but no simpler" - A. Einstein

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look [here](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/select/) for select box manipulation.
For what you want, i think [JSON](http://json.org/) will do the right job for you.
Anyhow, if i were you, i will do this way: 
When I change first select, i do an ajax request. With ajax response, i will populate the second box. Same for second box and there you have the third box populated with right data.