# Referencing a javascript object literal array

Tags: javascript, data-structures

How would you reference the models (Accord, CRV, Prius, etc) in this structure? 
Is this a bad structure to be able to extract the makes...then use a make to get the models...then use the model to get the options?

```
var cars = [
    {
        "makes"   : "Honda",
        "models"   : [
            {'Accord' : ["2dr","4dr"]} ,
            {'CRV'    : ["2dr","Hatchback"]} ,
            {'Pilot'  : ["base","superDuper"] }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "makes"   : "Toyota",
        "models"  : [
            {'Prius'   : ["green","reallyGreen"]} ,
            {'Camry'   : ["sporty","square"]} ,
            {'Corolla' : ["cheap","superFly"] }
        ]
    }
];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The structure:

```
var cars = [
    { name: 'Honda', models: [
                { name: 'Accord', features: ['2dr', '4dr'] },
                { name: 'CRV', features: ['2dr', 'Hatchback'] },
                { name: 'Pilot', features: ['base', 'superDuper'] }
        ]},

    { name: 'Toyota', models: [
                { name: 'Prius', features: ['green', 'superGreen'] },
                { name: 'Camry', features: ['sporty', 'square'] },
                { name: 'Corolla', features: ['cheap', 'superFly'] }
        ]}
];
```

I wrote about the traversal and everything else [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/using-javascript-and-jquery-to-populate-related-select-boxes-with-array-structu#180926).

Comment: I chose this answer because it answered the question "Is this bad structure...?" which was yes...by adding fixed "names" (i.e. name, models, etc.) it allows me to iterate over the data with loops (and other ways as Marko Dumic put in his other answer) thanks

Answer (score 6):

<strike>cars[0].models.Accord
    cars[0].models.CRV
    cars[0].models.Pilot</strike> (See [olliej](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180844/#180861)'s answer)

Though, it may be easier to use the following access concept:

```
cars.Honda.Accord
cars.Toyota.Prius
```

...using...

```
var cars = {
  Honda : {
    Accord : ["2dr", "4dr"],
    CRV    : ["2dr", "Hatchback"],
    Pilot  : ["base", "superDuper"]
  },
  Toyota : {
    Prius : ["green", "reallyGreen"],
    Camry : ["sporty", "square"],
    Corolla : ["cheap", "superFly"]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Jonathan's is correct, but he missed the additional level of Array's at the model level, so it should be

```
 cars[0].models[0].Accord
 cars[0].models[1].CRV
```

etc

I suspect you would find it easier to use a structure along the lines of:

```
var cars = [
{makes  : "Honda",
 models  : {
    Accord : ["2dr","4dr"],
    CRV  : ["2dr","Hatchback"],
    Pilot: ["base","superDuper"]  
 }
}, 
{makes   :"Toyota",
 models  : {
    Prius   : ["green","reallyGreen"],
    Camry   : ["sporty","square"],
    Corolla : ["cheap","superFly"]
 }
}];
```

In which the `models` array is replaced by an object (or associative array if you like)

[edit (olliej): tidying up code in second example]

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse models with this code:

```
for (var i = 0, carslen = cars.length; i < carslen; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, modelslen = cars[i].models.length; j < modelslen; j++) {
        // do something with cars[i].models[j]
    }
}
```

but I agree with Olliej about changing the structure of your JSON to his format.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't lump all your data into one big multidimensional array/object literal mess like that.  I'd encapsulate each object and use methods to access the data.  It'll mess with your brain a lot less.

Comment: This looks like a JSON response, so no methods for you.

Comment: The proper way to use JSON is to add a layer of code wrapper over your raw eval() function (mostly for security reasons). At that layer, you could properly encapsulate your data with a bit of work. It would be a good idea, at least.