# Iterating over the individual values of an array inside an object

Tags: javascript

hey guys i have a really complex array object literal , that i am trying to traverse , below is the object literal :

```
var all_locations = {
        'bangalore city' : ['bangalore city'],
        'bellary division' : ['bellary district' , 'koppala district' , 'davanagere district' , 
                                'shimoga district' , 'haveri district'],
        'mangalore division' : ['dakshina kanada district' , 'chikkamagalur district' , 'upupi district'],
        'kolar division' : ['kolar district' , 'chikkaballapura district' , 'bangalore rural district' ,
                           'citradurga district' , 'tumkur district'],
        'raichur division' : ['raichur district' , 'yadgir district' , 'gulbarga district' , 'bidar district'],
        'mysore division' : ['maysore district' , 'mandya district' , 'chamarajanagara district' , 'kodau district' , 
                             'hasan district'],
        'hubli devision' : ['dharwad district' , 'gadag district' , 'belgaum district' ,
                             'bagalkote district' , 'bijapur district']                                                  
    }
```

I am making use of `Object.keys` to traverse the above object literal , with the below for loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(all_locations).length ; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < all_locations[Object.keys(all_locations)[i]].length ; j++) {
            console.log(all_locations[Object.keys(all_locations)[i]])
        }
    }
```

the problem lies with this statement , `console.log(all_locations[Object.keys(all_locations)[i]])` ,
 i am not accessing the array properties inside , which is what i want to do ?

I saw this thread on SO [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180844/referencing-a-javascript-object-literal-array#) , but even after going through all the solutions in that answer (the last solution by Eric looked promising , but still did't solve my problem) , so how do i access the properties inside :

```
all_locations[Object.keys(all_locations)[i]] ??
```

**EDIT ::**

small example , on the 1st iteration of the loop i get the following result :

```
Array [ "bangalore city" ]
```

what i want is the string `"bangalore city"`.

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@AlexChar has the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30327500/1669279) (`console.log(all_locations[Object.keys(all_locations)[i]][j])`), of course, but you can easily avoid such problems by using the functional style of iterating over arrays and/or using semantic names for your variables:

```
Object.keys(all_locations).forEach(function(division){
  all_locations[division].forEach(function(district) {
    console.log(district);
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/esgrw9v5/ , Alex solution does't work ! see the edit in my question , and i will try your solution , but i'am not sure thats gonaa fit in my code , now that i have gone with for loops !