# Any plugins for simple content filtering that will run on a local machine?

Tags: jquery, html, mootools

I want to run an html file on a local android tablet and I would like to filter content in 2 layers.

- select a category
- Choose a price range (optional)
- Then a *style* sorter appears that changes the options depending on
  the category chosen

I searched but didn't find any jQuery plugins that do what I want, so I'd like to hear your tips if you know of any or if you know of any way I can do this.

Also, is it possible to do sortable pagination without php and mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to change the `select` options on the fly. There are several [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/using-javascript-and-jquery-to-populate-related-select-boxes-with-array-structu) on Stackoverflow that cover this topic.

As for jQuery plugins that do sorting and pagination - you can check out either the [tableSorter plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) or [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) - the latter is a bit more bloated with features, but offers a very slick 'search' option to your table - [DataTables example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html).

Both require you to have tabular HTML data, but both plugins handle all of the sorting and pagination for you (with options to customize default settings).