# Using custom tag CF_TwoSelectsRelated does not populate the 2nd SELECT box

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am using the ColdFusion CF_TwoSelectsRelated custom tag [by Nate Weiss](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1000288) to populate two dynamic SELECT boxes. The tag is in a CFFunction. The 2nd SELECT box is based on the selection from the 1st SELECT box. My first SELECT box is fine, but it does not populate results in my 2nd SELECT box. Here is my code:

```
<CFFunction ...>
    <CFQuery Name="Variables.AcctDelegationQuery" DataSource="#Request.ReportDataSource#" maxrows="301" blockfactor="100">
        SELECT distinct oa.op_location_code loc,
        oa.op_fund_num op_fund_num,
        oa.op_location_code||'-'||oa.op_fund_num loc_fund,
        oa.chart_num chart_num,
        oa.acct_num acct_num,
        oa.chart_num||'-'||oa.acct_num chart_acct
        FROM ...
        WHERE ...
        group by  oa.op_location_code, oa.op_fund_num , oa.op_location_code||'-'||oa.op_fund_num, oa.chart_num, oa.acct_num , oa.chart_num||'-'||oa.acct_num
        order by loc_fund, chart_acct
    </CFQuery>

    <CF_TwoSelectsRelated
        QUERY="Variables.AcctDelegationQuery"
        NAME1="LocFund"
        NAME2="ChartAcct"
        DISPLAY1="loc_fund"
        DISPLAY2="chart_acct"
        VALUE1="loc_fund"
        VALUE2="chart_acct"
        FORCEWIDTH1="30"
        FORCEWIDTH2="30"
        SIZE1="1"
        SIZE2="1"
        HTMLBETWEEN="<td>"
        EMPTYTEXT1="(Select a Fund)"
        EMPTYTEXT2="(Select an Account)"
        ONCHANGE=""
        FORMNAME="">
</CFFunction>
```

Thanks,
Kefang Feng

Comment: The best thing to do here is to *not* use those custom tags. So if you still have scope to revise your code, use JS (eg: JQuery etc) & AJAX calls to do this instead. TwoSelectsRelated.cfm might have had a place ten years ago, but it doesn't any more.

Comment: Thanks. I am using AJAX to implement the dynamic selections.

Answer (score 2):

Unhelpfully, off the top of my head , I can't remember what it was... but...
There is a bug in the original custom tag.

I submitted the change to Nate, but it was a long time ago and I don't actually ever recall getting a reply.

None the less - I no longer use it. I normally go for a jQuery solution.
Similarly, you might find this S.O post helpful: [Using javascript and jquery, to populate related select boxes with array structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180451/using-javascript-and-jquery-to-populate-related-select-boxes-with-array-structu)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you not use that tag at all.  The two major reasons are

1. It was written in 2002 and there are much better ways to achieve related selects than there were then.
2. It is based on a single query which limits it's usefulness.

What I think is the best way to do this now is to bind your 2 cfselects to methods in a cfc.  The documentation on cfselect and cfinput will have examples.

Comment: i would recommend using a JavaScript based approach versus using `cfselect`